# Adding Facebook Photo objects to Open Graph Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, photo-gallery

I've created a timeline app that adds events to user's timelines in the past. I've noticed its simple to add tags, places, and external images to OG objects and actions.

However, I can't seem to find a good way to connect to a facebook photo (i.e. a photo from the user's albums).  Adding a link to the photo's picture in the images field doesn't work the expected way without an access token (which will presumably expire)

For example:  /namespace:action?image=http://graph.facebook.com/10100111692798728/picture will show a '?' photo (in aggregations and elsewhere) unless you pass a valid access token in too (that can't work permanently). This is presumably because whatever identity is going out to request the photo is not allowed to access it this way.

It doesn't seem like you can connect your own actions to photo objects either.  Is there a solution to this that I've missed.  I'd really like user's to be able to add a photo from their facebook albums to an action from my app (i.e. them doing the 'action'). It would be nice if you didn't have to point directly at an image on FB's CDN somewhere, it would be even nicer if there was a way to point directly at the FB open graph object.

Thanks,
Grant

Comment: No @Tony I didn't.  My understanding is that this kind of thing is not offered via Facebook's API right now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect the action with Facebook photo like this:

```
POST /me/do:action?object=[objectId]&access_token=[valid access token]
```

If the `[objectId]` is an object id of existing photo - it will show the picture and correct link to the full size facebook photo on timeline.